# Doing an API, constructor for system private use only and another official, javadoc'ed and public to use. Advise on fix / pattern approach

Tags: java, constructor, design-patterns, private

I guess this is a bad pattern, whats the best approach to fix it?

I mean I would like everybody using a constructor with 2 arguments,but I need to leave default constructor because its implementing a listener which classloads it without args. I would like to hide default constructor to anyone else but the listener handler which uses it, and make the other the unique point to instantiate.

Is there any kind of annotation? any privacy modifier for certain classes (system caller one is not in the same package)?

Comment: What is forcing you to have this specific constructor? An interface which the listener requires you to use would not enforce a specific constructor. If you extend an abstract class that could require a specific constructor. If they're using reflection to instantiate your class then I don't think the protection level matters, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fine to me. You would do the same thing if you want to instantiate a class differently during unit testing.

Oh, I see you need a constructor that has more access than protected but less than public. Unfortunately that's not possible.

Comment: Maybe some suggested pattern or strategy then?

Answer (score 1):

You could put both your class `MyClass` and the listener `MyListener` that needs to use the empty constructor in the same package. Then, set the access of the empty constructor to **[package-level](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)**:

```
package com.stackoverflow.foo;

public class MyClass {
  MyClass () {  // package-private (no explicit access modifier) 
  }

  public MyClass(int a, int b) {  // public
  }
}

package com.stackoverflow.foo;

public class MyListener {
  private MyClass ref = new MyClass(); // MyListener is on the same package as MyClass, so this is valid
}
```

This way, you ensure that only classes that are on the same package as `MyClass` can use the default constructor.

Comment: But that was my last line :p : the class that handles the listener is in another jar (not mine), hence the problem